# Limit results from joined table to one row

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

Here is a simplified table structure:

```sql
TABLE products (
 product_id INT (primary key, auto_increment),
 category_id INT,
 product_title VARCHAR,
 etc
);

TABLE product_photos (
 product_photo_id (primary key, auto_increment),
 product_id INT,
 photo_href VARCHAR,
 photo_order INT
);
```

A product can have multiple photos, the first product photo for each product (based on the photo_order) is the default photo.

Now, I only need all of the photos on the product details page, but on pages where I am listing multiple products, for example a product directory page, I only want to display the default photo.

So what I am trying to do, is query a list of products including the default photo for each product.

This obviously doesn't work, it will return all photos with the product info duplicated for each photo:

```sql
SELECT p.*, ph.*
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_photos AS ph
ON p.product_id=ph.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_title ASC
```

I need to figure out how to do something like this, but I don't know the syntax (or if it is possible)

```sql
SELECT p.*, ph.*
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_photos AS ph
    ON p.product_id=ph.product_id  **ORDER BY ph.photo_order ASC LIMIT 1**
ORDER BY p.product_title ASC
```

**Edit: I figured out a solution with help from the answers below, thanks all!**

```sql
SELECT p.*, ph.*
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_photos AS ph 
    ON p.product_id=ph.product_id
    AND ph.photo_order =
    (
        SELECT MIN(z.photo_order)
        FROM product_photos AS z
        WHERE z.product_id=p.product_id
    )
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_title ASC
```

Comment: Pls provide an example of PRODUCT_PHOTOS - I want to see how PHOTO_ORDER controls the default because you didn't provide data types

Comment: photo_order is just an integer, it *should* be unique per product but not necessarily guaranteed

Comment: If you switch to a right join and order by: .product_title ASC, .photo_order ASC I think you will get one row per product and it will be the first photo. You will not see products that do not have a photo (which may be an issue). It should be a far simpler query though.

Comment: Yes that would be a problem, as there is no guarantee that all products will have at least one photo (most likely many will not)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT p.*,
       pp.*
  FROM PRODUCTS p
  JOIN PRODUCT_PHOTOS pp ON pp.product_id = p.product_id
  JOIN (SELECT x.product_id,
               MIN(x.photo_order) AS default_photo
          FROM PRODUCT_PHOTOS x
      GROUP BY x.product_id) y ON y.product_id = pp.product_id
                              AND y.default_photo  = pp.photo_order
```

Comment: i don't know that this does what he's asking.  he was specific that the photo_order field be used, not the product_photo_id field.

Comment: It does exactly what is needed, I just try to avoid subqueries when I can, hence the other answer.

Comment: @Wrikken: A join to a derived table/inline view isn't a subquery.  To me, at least...

Comment: agreed on the derived table.  did you change your anwser or did i completely misread it?  apologies if i was in the wrong.

Comment: ohoh, not getting into that. Not quite flame-war-bait, but whether a derived table is a subquery is very open for debate, which I will not start now. And it wasn't a criticism, my disuse of subqueries and / or derived tables sometimes borders the illogical.

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT p.*, ph.*
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN product_photos AS ph
    ON p.product_id = ph.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_photos AS ph2
    ON p.product_id = ph2.product_id
    AND ph2.photo_order < ph.photo_order
WHERE ph2.photo_order IS NULL
ORDER BY p.product_title ASC
```

Note the how it joins to the product_photos table twice. The `WHERE ph2.photo_order IS NULL` will throw out all but the lowest photo order. It won't protect you against duplicate product_id / photo_orders combo though, you could add a `GROUP BY` on p.id if that's the case.

Comment: Nice job. No sub query/derived table. Just need indexes on product_id and photo_order.

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT p.*, ph.*
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN product_photos AS ph ON p.product_id=ph.product_id
    ORDER BY p.product_title ASC, ph.photo_order ASC
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
  ....
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although this solution won't honor the photo_order column.

Comment: Try reversing the sort order.