# one to one result in mysql Query

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two table:

- **career**
- **career_details**

Table "**career**" contain fields (careerID,job_code)
Table "career_details" contain fields (id, careerID, name)

Let the values be `[(1,code1),(2,code2)]`--- career(table)
Let the values be

```
[

 ('1','1','codename1'),  
   ('2','1','codename11'),  
   ('3','2','codename22'),  
   ('4','2','codename222')


]
```

-- career_details(table)

Now if I write the query("`SELECT * FROM career c LEFT JOIN career_details cd ON c.career_id=cd.career_id WHERE 1`"), then it will give the result 4 rows but I need the result 2 rows only i.e

```
[(1,code1,1,1,codename1),(2,code2,3,2,codename22)]
```

Comment: Is it careerID or career_id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit results from joined table to one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978726/limit-results-from-joined-table-to-one-row)

Comment: How would MySQL know which detail to take?

Comment: This appears to be a `greatest-n-per-group` problem. Added a relevant tag. As a matter of fact, there are many [SO questions tagged `mysql` and `greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql), some of them having accepted answers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing left join, you should write inner join

Again as per your requirement, you need the first career details data that is first assigned with a career data. Please refer below link.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1c64/14

```
SELECT c.id,c.name as name ,cd.id as cdl_id,cd.career_id,cd.name as dtl_name FROM career_details cd  INNER JOIN careers c  ON c.id=cd.career_id
and cd.id in (select max(id) from career_details group by career_id);
```

Comment: I updated my query. Please look into the sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1c64/14

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM career c LEFT JOIN career_details cd ON c.career_id=cd.career_id 
group by c.id
```

Group by c.id will limit only one entry for a c.id in the result set.