# MySQL returning 1 image for each product

Tags: mysql

This is very similar to [Limit results from joined table to one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978726/limit-results-from-joined-table-to-one-row), but I'm struggling to get it to work exactly as I need...

The table structure is very similar:

```
CREATE TABLE tblProducts (
    intProductID int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    strProductName varchar(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intProductID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblProductImages (
    intImageID int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    intProductID int(11) NULL,
    strImageName varchar(255) NULL,
    intOrder int(11) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intImageID)
);
```

Populate the tables with:

```
INSERT INTO tblProducts (strProductName)
VALUES
('Product #1'), ('Product #2'), ('Product #3');

INSERT INTO tblProductImages (intProductID, strImageName, intOrder) 
VALUES
(1, 'image_for_1.jpg', 1), 
(2, '1st_image_for_2.jpg', 1), 
(2, '2nd_image_for_2.jpg', 2);
```

I want to do a SELECT that returns all 3 products, with appropriate images. Similar to:

```
intProductID, strProductName, strImageName
1, Product #1, image_for_1.jpg
2, Product #2, 1st_image_for_2.jpg
3, Product #3, NULL
```

A simple solution would be:

```
SELECT intProductID, strProductName, 
 (SELECT strImageName
  FROM tblProductImages
  WHERE tblProductImages.intProductID = tblProducts.intProductID
  ORDER BY intOrder
  LIMIT 1)
FROM tblProducts
```

But this fails if I want to add & return another field from the tblProductImages (AltText for example)

I've setup a Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/883c5/1

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the values inserted in tblProductImages ? Because they all have 1 as intProductId... And this doesn't looks coherent with the wanted result.

Comment: You need to use ``LEFT JOIN`` not that funky ``SELECT`` you are doing

Comment: Well spotted Raphaël - it's fixed. nrathaus - LEFT JOIN won't work because it will return 2 record (both images) for product 2 and I only want 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will work, but is quite ugly

```
select p.intProductId, p.strProductName, pi.strImageName 
from tblProducts p
inner join tblProductImages pi on pi.intProductID = p.intProductId
inner JOIN (select min(intOrder) minOrder, intProductID
           FROM tblProductImages
           GROUP BY intProductID) s
           on s.intProductID = p.intProductID and s.minOrder = pi.intOrder
union
select p.intProductId, p.strProductName, pi.strImageName
from tblProducts p
left join tblProductImages pi on pi.intProductID = p.intProductId
where pi.intProductID is null;
```

alternative :

```
select p.intProductId, p.strProductName, pi.strImageName
from tblProducts p
left join tblProductImages pi on pi.intProductID = p.intProductId
where pi.intProductId is null or pi.IntOrder = (select min(intOrder)
                                                from tblProductImages
                                                where intProductId = pi.intProductId);
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a947f/16)

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Raphaël. Your alternative is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation (specifically `GROUP BY`).  You want to `GROUP BY` the product name and use a `LEFT JOIN` so that the image does not need to exist.

```
SELECT strProductName, strImageName
FROM tblProducts LEFT JOIN tblProductImages USING (intProductID)
GROUP BY strProductName
```

Note that the image that is selected in this case is *random* (though usually it will be in `intImageID` order).  This assumes that the actual image retrieved is not important as long as it is associated with the given product.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1391e6/1

Comment: Thanks, but I'd tried this, but I'm afraid I do need to be able to set the order that the images are returned in.

Comment: @JezB what do you mean by that exactly?  The order that per-product images are returned in or the order that they are returned in the aggregate?

Comment: But I can't set the order of the images - in this case I may want 2nd_image_for_2.jpg first...

Comment: @JezB how would you know when to select what image?

Answer (score 0):

For that exact output, you might need to modify your insert statement for table tblProductImages as:

```
INSERT INTO tblProductImages (intProductID, strImageName, intOrder) VALUES
    (1, 'image_for_1.jpg', 1), (2, '1st_image_for_2.jpg', 1), (3, '2nd_image_for_3.jpg', 2);
```

And use the below Select statement:

```
SELECT tP.intProductID, tp.strProductName, tPI.strImageName
FROM tblProducts AS tP 
INNER JOIN tblProductImages AS tPI ON tP.intProductID = tPI.intProductID;
```

Comment: Sorry - I'd changed the INSERT to fix this. But the result still returns 2 records (both image) for product 2 & none for product 3...