# Limit number of rows per group from join (NOT to 1 row)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

Given these tables:

```
TABLE Stores (
 store_id INT,
 store_name VARCHAR,
 etc
);

TABLE Employees (
 employee_id INT,
 store_id INT,
 employee_name VARCHAR,
 currently_employed BOOLEAN,
 etc
);
```

I want to list the 15 longest-employed employees for each store (let's say the 15 with lowest `employee_id`), or ALL employees for a store if there are 15 who are `currently_employed='t'`. I want to do it with a join clause.

I've found a lot of examples of people doing this **only** for 1 row, usually a min or max (single longest-employed employee), but I want to basically do combine an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT` inside of the join. Some of those examples can be found here:

- [Limit results from joined table to one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978726/limit-results-from-joined-table-to-one-row)
- [MySQL returning 1 image for each product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353403/mysql-returning-1-image-for-each-product?lq=1)

I've also found decent examples for doing this store-by-store (I don't, I have about 5000 stores):

- [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

I've also seen that you can use `TOP` instead of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, but not for PostgreSQL.

I reckon that a join clause between the two tables isn't the only (or even necessarily best way) to do this, if it's possible to just work by distinct `store_id` inside of the employees table, so I'd be open to other approaches. Can always join afterwards.

As I'm very new to SQL, I'd like any theory background or additional explanation that can help me understand the principles at work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE)

The general solution to get the top n rows per group is with the window function `row_number()`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY employee_id) AS rn
   FROM   employees
   WHERE  currently_employed
   ) e
JOIN   stores s USING (store_id)
WHERE  rn <= 15
ORDER  BY store_id, e.rn;
```

- `PARTITION BY` should use `store_id`, which is guaranteed to be unique (as opposed to `store_name`).
- First identify rows in `employees`, *then* join to `stores`, that's cheaper.
- To get *15 rows* use `row_number()` not `rank()` (would be the wrong tool for the purpose). (While `employee_id` is unique, the difference doesn't show.)

#### [`LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

An alternative since Postgres **9.3** that typically performs (much) better in combination with a matching index, *especially* when retrieving a small selection from a big table. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

```sql
SELECT s.store_name, e.*
FROM   stores s
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *  -- better just the needed columns!
   FROM   employees e
   WHERE  e.store_id = s.store_id
   AND    e.currently_employed
   ORDER  BY e.employee_id
   LIMIT  15
   ) e
-- WHERE ... work with selected stores?
ORDER  BY s.store_name, e.store_id, e.employee_id;
```

The perfect index would be a partial multicolumn index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON employees (store_id, employee_id) WHERE  currently_employed;
```

Related example:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

Both versions exclude stores without current employees. There are ways around this if needed with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` ...

Answer (score 2):

A classic way of doing this would be with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html), such as `rank`:

```
SELECT employee_name, store_name
FROM   (SELECT employee_name, store_name, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY store_name ORDER BY employee_id ASC) AS rk
        FROM   employees e
        JOIN   stores s ON e.store_id = s.store_id) t
WHERE  rk <= 15
```