# Having Joins query with limit 10 on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have designer and design table

designer has many designs

I want to get all designers with 10 designs for each designer

Is there way I can do it in a single query in either postgresql, mysql

Comment: where is query ? and which database ?

Comment: Please refine your question, add some details like table structure, your current query etc.

Answer (score 1):

For best performance in **Postgres** (not possible in MySQL) use a **`LATERAL`** join:

```
SELECT d.designer, d1.design  -- whatever columns you need
FROM   designer d
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *                   -- or just needed columns
   FROM   design
   WHERE  designer_id = d.designer_id
   -- ORDER  BY ???           -- you may want to pick certain designs
   LIMIT  10
   ) d1 ON true
ORDER  BY d.designer_id, d.design_id;  -- or whatever
```

This gives you 10 designs per designer - or as many as he/she has if there are fewer.

- `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` keeps designers in the result that don't have a single design (yet).

  - [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
  - [Call a set-returning function with an array argument multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107915/call-a-set-returning-function-with-an-array-argument-multiple-times/26514968#26514968)
- You get best performance if you add an `ORDER BY` clause that matches an existing **index** on `design` like:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX foo ON design (designer_id, design_id)
  ```

  Then, in the subquery `d1` in above query:

  ```
  ...
  ORDER  BY design_id
  ...
  ```

  Now Postgres can pick the top items from the index directly.

Related answer with more details:

- [Limit number of rows per group from join (NOT to 1 row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768144/limit-number-of-rows-per-group-from-join-not-to-1-row/30768557#30768557)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  ( 
    Select row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.designer ORDER BY b.design DESC) rn,
        a.* ,b.* 
    from a
    inner join  b
        on a.id = b.id
    ) 
    where rn <= 10
```

mysql doesn't have window functions, which you need, so this is postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can make use of user-defined variables to emulate some of the analytic functions available in other databases...

```
  SELECT v.designer_id
       , v.design_id
    FROM ( SELECT @rn := IF(r.id = @prev_r_id,@rn+1,1) AS rn
                , @prev_r_id := r.id AS designer_id
                , d.id AS design_id
             FROM (SELECT @rn := 0, @prev_r_id := NULL) i
            CROSS
             JOIN designer r
             LEFT
             JOIN design d
               ON d.designer_id = r.id
            ORDER BY r.id, d.id
         ) v 
   WHERE v.rn <= 10
   ORDER BY v.designer_id, v.design_id
```

You can run just the inline view query (`v`) to see what that returns. What it does is order the rows by `designer_id`, and compares the value from the current row to the value from the previous row... if they match, it increments `@rn` by 1, otherwise, it resets `@rn` to 1. Net effect is that we get an ascending integer sequence from `rn` for each designer_id... 1,2,3.

The outer query filters out the rows where `rn` is greater than 10.

If a given `designer` has fewer than ten `designs`, we get fewer than ten rows for that `designer`.