# Postgres Query to fetch multiple entities per item

Tags: postgresql

How to fetch top x (say 2 - ordered by Score) posts for the give user ids (say 10 and 20) in a single query?

Table:

**Posts**

| ID | USER_ID | CONTENT | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | C1 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | C2 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | C3 | 3 |
| 4 | 30 | C4 | 4 |
| 5 | 10 | C5 | 5 |
| 6 | 10 | C6 | 6 |
| 7 | 20 | C7 | 7 |
| 8 | 20 | C8 | 8 |

**Desired Output:**

| ID | USER_ID | CONTENT | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | C5 | 5 |
| 6 | 10 | C6 | 6 |
| 7 | 20 | C7 | 7 |
| 8 | 20 | C8 | 8 |

Comment: Found an answer here - can be done using lateral join https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/1747274

Comment: This one should fit even closer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768557/939860